# How to return to some activity after button finish is clicked

Tags: android

I have this in last activity where is inserted into database:

```
btnFinish = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFinish);

    btnFinish.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            if (extras != null) {
                Name = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Name");
                Email = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Email");
                Phone = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Phone");
            }               
            new SummaryAsyncTask().execute((Void) null);                
            startActivity(getIntent());

        }
    });
```

Currently when I click on `btnfinish` is reload the same activity. What I want is to back to some activity. Not previous but some activity.. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the *Activity class* where you want to redirect it.
 You have written

> startActivity(getIntent());

which means the same Activity, will definitely reloads the same activity.

Change it to :

```
startActivity(new Intent(ThisActivityName.this, NetxActivtiy.class));
```

Hope it helps ツ

Answer (score 1):

The following code snippet is enough

```
Intent toSomeActivity=new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,SomeActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("Name",Name);
intent.putExtra("Email",Email);
intent.putExtra("Phone",Phone);
startActivity(toSomeActivity);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get to any activity from where ever you are by simply calling the initiation of the activity you want to go to. try making a method for your button in your main and call it in the current method.

```
//the method in the main activity
public void homeButton()
{
    HomeButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.home_button);
    HomeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            initHomeActivity();
        }
    });
}
```

...

```
//the activity initiation to be called by the onClick
public void initHomeActivity()
{
    homeActivity = new HomeActivity(this);
    homeActivity.init();
}
```

...

```
MainActivity mainActivity
//calling the method from the current activity
public void init() {
    mainActivity.setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_out);
    mainActivity.homeButton();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your manifest, add this to your activity:

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

With this parameter, each time your activity restarts, it will return to the same instance.

Answer (score 1):

> Currently when I click on btnfinish is reload the same activity. What I want is to back to some activity. Not previous but some activity.. Is that possible?

Your problem is this line:

```
startActivity(getIntent());  //getIntent returns intent that started this activity
```

**So** it just reloads that activity.

You would need to do:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, SomeActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Which will specify that you need to open `SomeActivity`.

Hope it helps.